# React - useReducer and useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-hooks

I started to implement the reducer pattern in a new project, and i want to know if 
`useReducer` hook has the same problem with `async immutability` as the `useState` hook.

*What do i mean:*

```
const [state, setState] = useState('');

const handleChange = e => {

 setState(e.target.value);

 // It doesn't give the current value, it gives the previous one, which is ''
 console.log(state);

 // So i need to set the current value in a variable to avoid the async immutability
 const currentValue = e.target.value;

 console.log(currentValue);

 e.stopPropagation();
}

<input type='text' value={state} onChange={handleChange}>PRESS</button>
```

For the `useReducer` hook i need to do the same thing: **set the current `change` in a `variable`** ?

Comment: <input type='text'  value={state} onChange={handleChange}>PRESS</button> ?

Comment: Not to set a controlled component. but to access the current value.

Comment: yes you have to do the same thing. can I know your use case?

Comment: Get the `value` from an `input` and set it in some `paragraph` to display it's `info`

Answer (score 0):

Not matter what you use `useState` or `useReducer`, you will see the updated values in next cycle of render.

This is not a flaw but a design. If you want to do something with the updated value use `useEffect`, which runs after every render.

So it will have the fresh value with it.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

To avoid the `useReducer` hook immutability we need to set the `current value` in a `variable`. And then access that variable.

```
const initialState = {
 value: ''
};

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(SomeReducerFunction, initialState);

const handleChange = e => {

 dispatch({type: SOME_ACTION_TYPE, payload: e.target.value });

 const currentValue = e.target.value;

 console.log(currentValue);

 e.stopPropagation();
}

<input type='text' value={state} onChange={handleChange}>PRESS</button>
```